Reset STM32 CM7 Core from CM4 core
I have a STM32H747XI project. This MCU has both CM4 and CM7 cores. I can reset both of them, when I use NVIC_SystemReset() function. How can I reset only CM7 core from CM4 core?

Do they have individual watchdogs or is there just one? In case of several, just write an invalid number to the watchdog.


Trigger a Core Reset by using MCU's Peripheral. It's also called System Control Space (SCS) System Control Block (SCB).

Another way is CM7 Core Reset Register, it needs to be accessed. A reset on the CM7 core can be triggered by using registers.



NVIC_SystemReset() already uses SCB->AIRCR register which triggers a system wide reset.
